# When reading from csv to dataframe, with 4 columns no error, with 5 columns Settingwithcopy error when updating df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It's really weird but I have tried all the solutions shared here so sharing my main code.

```
first_df = pd.read_csv(f'C:\\Users\\y\\AlgoTrading\\Algo Live\\Final\\stockpicks\\yy.txt', sep=",",names=['ticker','entry2','entry3','entry4'])
first_df.set_index('ticker',inplace=True)
first_df
```

Now when I update using the below code and it works fine.

```
first_df.loc["stock"].entry2 = False
```

No errors, but when I read 5 columns

```
first_df = pd.read_csv(f'C:\\Users\\y\\AlgoTrading\\Algo Live\\Final\\stockpicks\\yy.txt', sep=",",names=['ticker','entry2','entry3','entry4','entry5'])
first_df.set_index('ticker',inplace=True)
first_df
```

Now when I update using the below code and it throws error and doesn't update anything in the dataframe.

```
first_df.loc["stock"].entry2 = False
```

this is how the file looks

> When 4 - OIL,False,True,True
> When 5 - SHYAMMETL,True,True,True,2022-12-21 09:55:13.137608

Any help please?

I have tried all the methods I could find, including creating copy and such.

Comment: Use `first_df.loc["stock", "entry2"]`

Comment: That worked! Checking in live if it does too, but why did this work? Specially what difference does it make between 4 columns and 5?

Comment: Have you read the duplicate link? ;)  No matter the difference, you can't always predict when slicing will generate a copy, do always slice correctly.